# Raid array Devices are not removed

Tags: software-raid

cat /proc/mdstat

```
Personalities : [raid1] [raid0] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [linear] [raid10] 
md11 : active raid10 sde1[3] sdj1[4](F)
      286743936 blocks 64K chunks 2 near-copies [4/1] [___U] [1:1:3:0]
      [=>...................]  resync =  8.0% (23210368/286743936) finish=67874.1min speed=64K/sec
```

umount /dev/md11

```
umount: /dev/md11: not mounted
```

mdadm --stop /dev/md11

```
mdadm: fail to stop array /dev/md11: Device or resource busy
```

mdadm --manage --set-faulty /dev/md7 /dev/sdh1

```
mdadm: set /dev/sdh1 faulty in /dev/md7
```

mdadm -r /dev/md7 /dev/sdh1

```
mdadm: hot remove failed for /dev/sdh1: Device or resource busy
```

cat /proc/mdstat

```
Personalities : [raid1] [raid0] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [linear] [raid10] 
md11 : active raid10 sde1[3] sdj1[4](F)
      286743936 blocks 64K chunks 2 near-copies [4/1] [___U] [1:1:3:0]
      [=>...................]  resync =  8.0% (23210368/286743936) finish=67874.1min speed=64K/sec
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm no expert in this, but isnt the RAID rebuilding?

Comment: i know is not rebuilding , how to slove this

Comment: No, it is rebuilding. "resync =  8.0%"

Comment: is not modified this is stop , i am absorve from 3 days it shows same "resync =8.0%"

Comment: can u try this create raid 10 with 4 raid devices, after that mount to one directory, in directory add one file and some texts and save it. after that remove two raid devices one by one. after that edit the contents of file of already mounted. and try remove for other raid devices. ( i follow this way i got problem )